# Echo out multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that gives me multiple arrays when submit. My question is if there is a smart way to echo out (to show the user) all the arrays instead of doing a foreach for each array?

Could a solution be to do a function with a foreach loop?

**HTML from the TASKS input:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tasks[<?php echo($value[0]);?>]"value=<?php echo($key[0]);?>></td>
```

**My PHP script:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $pickup_at = $_POST['pickup_at'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];
     $price = $_POST['price'];
     $part_missing = $_POST['part_missing'];
```

**Foreach ex. on the TASKS array**

```
foreach($tasks as $key => $keys)
{
   echo $key ."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe: var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST)

Comment: ... @HarryFink I just updated my question. I need to show the result to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the arrays should have indexes in parallel. You only need to use the indexes from one of them, and can then use that as indexes into all the rest:

```
foreach ($tasks as $i => $task) {
    echo "Task $i: $task<br>";
    echo "  User: {$user[$i]}<br>";
    echo "  Pickup at: {$pickup_at[$i]}<br>";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($tasks as $key => $keys)
{
   echo $key ."<br>";
}
```

If its just use to add BR in keys another ways is

```
// will give you same output that foreach() gives you.
echo implode("<br>", array_keys($tasks));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
foreach($tasks as $key => $keys) {
    echo $key ."<br>";
}
```

you can do:

```
echo(implode('<br>', $tasks));
```

This puts `<br>` between the elements of `$task` and produces a string. Depending on the HTML context where you `echo` the string you may need or may need not to append an extra `<br>` after the last element.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your form. Your html sholud be this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tasks[]" value="<?php echo($value[0]);?>"></td>
```

Insted of this:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="tasks[<?php echo($value[0]);?>]"value=<?php echo($key[0]);?>></td>
```

After that you can print the values like this:

```
  echo implode(',',$tasks);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($tasks); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($tasks, true) . '</pre>';` is much better than using 3 statements.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do some kind of iteration - `foreach` being the most obvious. You can also use other native functions like [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
array_walk($array, function($val, $key) {
   echo $key, PHP_EOL;
});
```

But it does't really add anything here. I'd stick with `foreach` or `var_dump`.